# how to copy data from one table to another, with id's changing and id<>parentid relationship remaining correct?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

i have two tables:

new_table

> id | parentid | f1 | f2 | customerid

initial_table (does not have customerid)

> id | parentid | f1 | f2

**what i need to do is move ALL items from initial_table to new_table. however, id's change (auto generated) in the new_table!**

--

so, my idea (for now) is:

1 - move all data except `id` and `parentid` from initial_table to new_table

2 - use a lookup_table with

> id | originalparentid | newparentid | customerid

3 -  go through the lookup_table and update the new_table parentid column with the new `parentid`'s

--

so...

**question - 1 - is this the right way?**

**question - 2a - if yes, how to do it?**

**question - 2b - if no, how then?**

the problem in 2 is that i am doing this from a trigger and `customerid` is `SELECT @customerid = id FROM inserted` and this is fine. then i am doing

```
INSERT INTO new_table (f1, f2, customerid)
SELECT f1, f2 @customerid FROM initial_table
```

but i don't get the new id's from new_table when i do it like that.

--

so, please, help me write this trigger:

**i need to copy all data from initial_table to new_table with the problem that the id's will change and i need to update the parentid's accordingly in the new_table**

thnx

--

here is my current trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER Copy
ON dbo.Customers

FOR INSERT
AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION

/* variables */
DECLARE
    @customerid bigint

SELECT @customerid = id FROM inserted

/* insert all for this customer */
INSERT INTO new_table (f1, f2, customerid)
    SELECT f1, f2 @customerid FROM initial_table

/* TODO: add entries to lookup table */

/* TODO: fix the pages' parentid's */

/* execute */
COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO
```

Comment: Can't you just enable `IDENTITY INSERT` on the new table and disable it after the `INSERT`?

Comment: ah k - get it now. the problem still is - that the new_table already has some data in it and it may conflict with the new inserts. so would still need this solution above, because i need then still need a lookup table!? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just turn `IDENTITY INSERT` off for the initial insert and avoid this whole mess.  Is there any reason you can't do that?  Something like this should do it:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Customers ON
```

Then when you are done just run

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Customers OFF
```

Comment: perhaps the answer is YES, but i then need some info on what to insert as id's? i mean, how to get correct values to use on insert and not ones already used or something... maybe you can expand on that? :p

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Customers ON` before inserting the values and `OFF` after that?

Comment: @Lamak, just reading about it and YES i also think it should be that way. was probably just a miss-type in speed...

Comment: @b0x0rz, if you are starting with an empty table (which it sounds like you should be) you just need to select all columns from the source table (including the id) and insert them into the new table.  Then you can insert records into child tables that reference the new table.

Comment: the table is not empty. but i think i can make it work with the identity insert.